# How can I create dynamic API's in ASP.net Core 2

Tags: c#, api, controller, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to know how to create API's **dynamically** by calling another API then passing `[API name]` and `[API parameters]`, let's we assume that we have this API, like the one shown here:

[image: Calling API]

```
[HttpPost("GenerateApi")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public IActionResult GenerateApi(RootObject ro)
{           
   //Here I need piece of code to create API dynamically
   return Ok(new { ro.apiName, ro.parameters });       
}
```

Here are the models:

```
public class RootObject
{
   public string apiName { get; set; }
   public List<parameter> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class parameter
{
   public string parameterName { get; set; }
   public dynamic parameterType { get; set; }
}
```

Now what needs to be done, is to create **dynamic API** in controller.

So then we would have the API created they can be called from their URL like this

```
www.example.com/api/v1/[controller]/[apiName]/{[parameter1_value]}/{[parameter2_value]}
```

Can you please provide me some insight of this.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea..... what's the point of this? You should follow the **SOLID** principles of system design - and the **S** there stands for **Single Responsibility Principle** which says a piece of code should do **one thing** and **one thing only**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I want to let user create his API dynamically by calling this API [GenerateApi], if you have another good idea or Suggestion please help @marc_s

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522242/how-to-dynamically-create-web-apis-rest-apis-in-selfhosted-owin-server

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will read the document @Richard

Comment: You could use query parameters. There is some code to do this and generate the object using `ExpandoObject` in [this](https://github.com/KevinDockx/ImplementingAdvancedRESTfulConcernsAspNetCore3/tree/master/Finished%20sample/CourseLibrary/CourseLibrary.API) repo. There is a very good course to go along with it, if you can swing the sub cost it would be worth imo.

Comment: Thanks for help .. put this project in .net core 3. @TylerHundley

Comment: I'm not familiar with .net core 3, Is it very different from .net core 2?@TylerHundley

Answer (score 0):

Found some thing can help in MVC. In case somebody else is looking for this, I need to overwrite the DefaultHttpControllerSelector. Here is a very nice article on the subject: [link](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/) So basically for my use case mentioned above, I need to create a new AppDomain, start my service in it, and load my assemblies dynamically at runtime. I finally need to overwrite the DefaultHttpControllerSelector to catch the request. When the request arrive, it have then control on which controller I want to use. There I can update the controller dynamically by loading a new assembly, etc. Main thing to be careful on is that this is executed for each request so it could easily impact performance and memory. So I will implement my own caching of controller.